# Django: Retrieving IDs of manyToMany fields quickly

Tags: python, database, django, postgresql, m2m

I have the following model schema in Django (with Postgres).

```
class A(Models.model):
    related = models.ManyToManyField("self", null=True)
```

Given a QuerySet of A, I would like to return a dictionary mapping each instance of `A` in the QuerySet to a list of `id`s of its `related` instances as quickly as possible.

I can surely iterate through each A and query the related field, but is there a more optimal way?

Answer (score 25):

According you have Three instances. You can use the `values_list` method to retrieve just the results and from this result get just the ID's of their `related` instances.
I use the `pk` field to be my filter because i don't know your scheme, but you can use anything, just must be a `QuerySet`.

```
>>> result = A.objects.filter(pk=1)
>>> result.values('related__id')
[{'id': 2}, {'id': 3}]
>>> result.values_list('related__id')
[(2,), (3,)]
>>> result.values_list('related__id', flat=True)
[2, 3]
```

Comment: That's what I've been doing, but the problem is that I need to filter on more than one `pk` (e.g. `A.objects.filter(pk__in=[1,2,6])`). I'd like a list of lists, where the nth inner list is like the `values_list` here, but corresponding to the nth `pk`.

Comment: You can also do instance.related.values('id', flat=True), if you have a single model instance already.

Comment: `result.values_list` appears to return a QuerySet these days. It can easily be converted back to a list with `list(result.values_list)`

Answer (score 1):

You can get pretty close like this:

```
qs = A.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch(
                      'related', 
                      queryset=A.objects.only('pk'), 
                      to_attr='related_insts')).in_bulk(my_list_of_pks)
```

This will give a mapping from pks of the current object to the instance itself, so you can iterate through as follows:

```
for pk, inst in qs.iteritems():
  related_ids = (related.pk for related in inst.related_insts)
```

Or given an instance, you can do a fast lookup like so:

```
related_ids = (related.pk for related in qs[instance.pk]).
```

This method maps the instance ids to the related ids (indirectly) since you specifically requested a dictionary. If you aren't doing lookups, you may want the following instead:

```
qs = A.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch(
        'related', 
        queryset=A.objects.only('pk'), 
        to_attr='related_insts')).filter(pk__in=my_list_of_pks)
for inst in qs:
  related_ids = (related.pk for related in inst.related_insts)
```

You may take note of the use of `only` to only pull the pks from the db. There is an [open ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/26565) to allow the use of `values` and (I presume) `values_list` in Prefetch queries. This would allow you to do the following.

```
qs = A.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch(
        'related', 
        queryset=A.objects.values_list('pk', flat=True), 
        to_attr='related_ids')).filter(pk__in=my_list_of_pks)
for inst in qs:
  related_ids = inst.related_ids
```

You could of course optimize further, for example by using `qs.only('related_insts')` on the primary queryset, but make sure you aren't doing anything with these instances-- they're essentially just expensive containers to hold your related_ids.

I believe this is the best that's available for now (without custom queries). To get to exactly what you want, two things are needed:

1. The feature above is implemented
2. `values_list` is made to work with Prefetch `to_attr` like it does for annotations.

With these two things in place (and continuing the above example) you could do the following to get exactly what you requested:

```
d = qs.values_list('related_ids', flat=True).in_bulk()
for pk, related_pks in d.items():
    print 'Containing Objects %s' % pk
    print 'Related objects %s' % related_pks
# And lookups
print 'Object %d has related objects %s' % (20, d[20])
```

I've left off some details explaining things, but it should be pretty clear from the documentation. If you need any clarification, don't hesitate!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Postgres:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import ArrayAgg

qs = A.objects.filter(pk__in=[1,2,6]).annotate(related_ids=ArrayAgg('related')).only('id')
mapping = {a.id: a.related_ids for a in qs}
```

You can also use filter/ordering in the ArrayAgg.